# How can I create a border/frame around an image?

Tags: c#

My code:

```
private void CreateAnimatedGif(List<string> GifsFilesRadar , List<string> GifsFilesSatellite)//string FileName1 , string FileName2)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    DirectoryInfo inf = new DirectoryInfo(tempGifFiles);
    FileInfo[] fi = inf.GetFiles("*.gif");
    for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
    {
        Bitmap file1 = new Bitmap(GifsFilesRadar[i]);
        Bitmap file2 = new Bitmap(GifsFilesSatellite[i]);
        //calculate the new width proportionally to the new height it will have
        int newWidth = file1.Width + file1.Width / (file2.Height / (file2.Height - file1.Height));

        bitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth + file2.Width, Math.Max(file1.Height, file2.Height));
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            //high quality rendering and interpolation mode
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            //resize the left image
            g.DrawImage(file1, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, file2.Height));
            g.DrawImage(file2, newWidth, 0);
            string t = @"d:\GifsForAnimations" + "\\" + i.ToString("D6") + ".Gif";
            bitmap.Save(t, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            if (i == 4)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    List<string> gif = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\GifsForAnimations");
    FileInfo[] finfo = info.GetFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < finfo.Length; i++)
    {
        gif.Add(finfo[i].FullName);
    }
    newFile.MakeGIF(gif, @"d:\newGifAnim.gif", 80, true);
}
```

In the end I have new animated gif file.
Now I have the border and these are the locations:

- Bottom left corner: 232.0,408.0
- Top left corner: 232.0,211.0
- Top right corner: 524.0,211.0
- Bottom right corner: 524.0,408.0

I want to add on each image a frame around it to mark the border around. Let's say the border will be in Red and the border line size will be 5 pixels.

How can I create the rectangle around existing bitmap or gif file ?
It doesn't have to be connected to my example code here but how do I create the frame/border around the image with the locations I have ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add this line after `g.DrawImage(file2, newWidth, 0);`

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5), new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, file2.Height));
```

Here is a small test method so you can see it working

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\avatar63.jpg");
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5), new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
        }
        bitmap.Save(@"C:\avatar63New.jpg");
    }
```

Before: [image] After:  [image]

You can add the rectagle anywhere you want, tou jst need to supply the `X,Y,Width,Height`

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.LimeGreen, 5), new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100));
```

Using your 4 point structure this should work

```
   Point topLeft = new Point(232,211 );
   Point topRightr = new Point(232, 408);
   Point bottomLeft = new Point(524, 211);
   Point bottomRight = new Point(524, 408);

   g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.LimeGreen, 5), new Rectangle(topLeft, new Size(topRightr.X - topLeft.X, bottomLeft.Y - topLeft.Y)));

  // TopLeft = rectangle location
  // TopRight.X - TopLeft.X = Width of rectangle
  // BottomLeft.Y - TopLeft.Y = height of rectangle
```

[image]

Comment: sa_ddam213 working. And if I want to use to create this rectangle with the numbers points locations in my question ? 232,408 and 232,211 and 524,211 and 524,408 can you show me in the line you did in the answer how to do it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, So you just want to draw rectagles on the image not around the image? if you post a quick paint image of what you mean I can help more :)

Comment: sa_ddam213 what I mean is that I have one big image and inside this image I have a smaller image on the locations I mentioned above and I want to make a rectenagle around the smaller image that is inside the bigger one. That's why I asked how to use the locations/numbers I gave above. Now it will just create a smaller rectangle inside the image but later on after I will add the second smaller image the rectangle will be around it.

Comment: g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.LimeGreen, 5), new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)); this line there are four numbers: 50,50,100,100 and my numbers I have: 232,408 and 232,211 and 524,211 and 524,408 each two numbers are a point. So I have four points so how do I build the rectangle with this points ?

Comment: Numbers I mean coordinates of each point. 232,408 is a coordinate/point of the rectangle I want to draw. And so on.

Comment: So these points are the location of the small images on the big image? why don't you just draw the border around the smaller image before adding to the big image, where are these points comming from???

Comment: Updated answer with what I THINK you mean :)

Comment: FFR: I had a problem of margin/padding (in the picture of the OP you can see that the right border is thinner then the left one). If any1 got that, the solution is to use the property `Alignment` of `Pen` class.
`yourPen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;`