# How to draw Circle around Image using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

```
        byte[] byt = DMC_StudentImage;
        Image img = Image.GetInstance(byt);
        float width = 100f;
        float height = 100f;

        PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;            
        PdfTemplate temp = content.CreateTemplate(width, height);           
        temp.Ellipse(0, 0, width, height);
        temp.Clip();
        temp.NewPath();
        temp.AddImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
        Image clipped = Image.GetInstance(temp);
```

I have successfully clip an image with the help of above code as showing bellow in image 1, now i want to add circle around image as showing bellow in image 2.
[image]

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/round-image-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593261/5830472

Comment: Merely remember to first draw the outer circle, then clip to the inner circle. Or use save-/restore-graphics-state operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a png image with the back circle and put it after adding the image to the document.